# keys for each datatype

Tags: winforms

Is it possible in Windows Forms to constrain input to is data type.

For instance if i want to insert a Date in a Textbox, i be limited to use only this chars [0-9,/]

Is there a easy and fast way to do this?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're doing something *other* than a date, use `MaskedTextBox`.  Do use `DateTimePicker` for dates though.

Documentation on the [MaskedTextBox.Mask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask.aspx) property will tell you how to specify the text you want.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically for dates there is a [DateTimePicker control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.aspx) in winforms. With which you can specify a format to limit the characters you want to use to type the date.

For example: `dateTimePicker.CustomFormat = "dd/MM/yy";` or `dateTimePicker.CustomFormat = "dd-MM-yy";`